# getting the newest row inserted

Tags: php, mysql

In my table there is a column `date` in `datetime - current timestamp` format.
I already have this code which works well:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC');
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){...
```

Is it possible to get the newest row inserted (max date), from the above code, without writing a separate function?

If not, here is my try:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT MAX(date) FROM posts");
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$itemtop = $row['date'];
```

But I'm getting error - `Undefined index date in...`

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LIMIT`:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1');
$row = $stmt->fetch();   // fetch the most recent single record
$itemtop = $row['date']; // ...and whatever other columns you want
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved.

Answer (score 2):

Update code like below:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT MAX(date) as date FROM posts");
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$itemtop = $row['date'];
```

Also, you can find newest data Using SQL `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY`. Then you need to change your SQL LIKE Below.

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1');
```